# rails pass value from drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What would be the most efficient way of accomplishing the following:  Grab a value from a drop down and pass it with a search function into model.

Here is the html for search:

```
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
```

Here is the code in controller:

```
def index
  @trucks = Truck.search(params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @trucks }
end
```

end

Here is the model

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('truck_no LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
```

end

In the model I have `'truck_no LIKE ?'`

I would like it to become `column_name + ' LIKE ?'` where I pass in the column name through the method parameter.  How would I setup my drop down list in the html and pass it all the way to the controller?  What is the best way of accomplishing this?

Edit: forgot to mention, the drop down should display things like Truck Number, but pass in the value truck_no

Comment: However you do it, make sure to escape the column_name passed to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: right, i'm trying to avoid things like sql injection, I do not know how to accomplish it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just make sure that you have validation for the input on your end.  Never trust that input that you receive is going to be clean and you should cover all your risks (for SQL injections, that is)

Comment: well the search box is escaped, check the model.  they can't sql inject with search, I am worried about how to do this with drop down list, theoretically they can't change values for drop down list so it should be fine whichever way I do it, but I'm looking for advice on how to do this, an example hopefully.  I've never worked with drop downs before.  I found this website but it doesn't explain well, i'm confused as to how it works.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is **the base** for you:

```
# view
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= select_tag :search_column, options_for_select(Truck.column_names, params[:search_column]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>

# controller
def index
  @trucks = Truck.search(params[:search], params[:search_column])

# model
def self.search(keyword, column_name)
  if self.column_names.include?(column_name.to_s)
    where("trucks.#{column_name} LIKE ?", "%#{keyword}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

There is **several improvements** you can do here:

- Add the translation to the `select_field_tag` to see the translated attributes
- Add a class method that will return only the columns you want to be "searchable"
- Use the ActiveRecord's method `sanitize` to make sure the `column_name` is safe

I can help you with the improvements if you need.

---

## Class Method returning the searchable columns:

Here we have a choice, should we get all the columns and take off some of them? OR should we just select the one we want? The first option implies that if you add an attribute to the model, it will be by default added to the options, unless you take it off. The reverse will happen with the second option:

```
# model
# This method should return the columns defined in the `wanted_columns` array
def self.searchable_columns
  wanted_columns = ['name', 'description', 'etc' ]
  self.column_names.select{ |column| wanted_column.include?(column) }
end
# This method will return the columns NOT IN the `unwanted_columns` array
def self.searchable_columns
  unwanted_column = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
  self.column_names.reject{ |column| unwanted_column.include?(column) }
end

# view
<%= select_tag :search_column, options_for_select(Truck.searchable_columns, params[:search_column]) %>
```

## Display the translation and not the column name

```
# model
# This method return an array of arrays formatted like following:
# [ ['Name', 'name'], ['Truck Number', 'truck_no'] ]
def self.translated_searchable_columns
  columns = self.searchable_columns
  result = columns.map{ |column| [Truck.human_attribute_name(column.to_sym), column] }
  result
end

# view
<%= select_tag :search_column, options_for_select(Truck.translated_searchable_columns, params[:search_column]) %>
```

Comment: I would love your help with the improvements, first though I would like to understand what you did here so that I may understand the improvements.  So you are creating drop down options based on column names.  I tried adding just that first and it would not load the page.  Error I got was ndefined method `options' for #<#<Class:0x143d840>:0x1a86080>  Where is options method suppose to come from?

Comment: ok I saw your change so I tried it again and next method it is wondering about is select field tag:  undefined method `select_field_tag' for #<#<Class:0x143d840>:0x1a87568>  I changed it to select_tag and it worked.  It is listing all the drop downs by my column names in the database.  However if a user looks at these field names, they won't understand what they are.  Is there another way for this to work?

Comment: Ah, my bad, it is actually the method `options_for_select` that I wanted to use. It is a ActionView/Form Helper that allows you to create easily the `<option></option>` tags for the `<select></select>` - It is `select_tag` the right method (Gosh I need some sleep...)

Comment: it's all good MrYoshiji, I appreciate the effort alone!  Back to my question, so how can I list more appropriate names in the drop down, can I implement .titleize somehow but still pass in the values to the model that are currently listed?

Comment: I updated my answer @Bagzli with the Improvements, don't hesitate to ask more question if you need

Comment: so I have look at both examples, in top example you are having an option of being able to chose a column you want searchable, but in that example it still uses column names to display.  In second option you can see column names but you can't pick which columns you don't want to be searchable, correct?

Comment: Nope, the method `self.searchable_columns` is used in  `self.translated_searchable_columns`, So you have to implement one of the two options for `self.searchable_columns` and then implement `self.translated_searchable_columns`

Comment: ok and they are both methods that go into model?  translated doesn't need to go into controller?

Comment: `self.searchable_columns` and `self.translated_searchable_columns` can be implemented in the Truck Model. Actually, the "best" place for `self.translated_searchable_columns` would be in a TruckHelper, but it is not mandatory since you don't need tons of "display/format" methods about the Truck model.

Comment: alright, I just got 1 last thing confusing me, how come there are 2 views posted, 1 in each example?

Comment: I gave you an example for each method I was showing you. The one you want is `select_tag :search_column, options_for_select(Truck.translated_searchable_columns, params[:search_column])`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35149/discussion-between-bagzli-and-mryoshiji)